# BaseController to handle client factory

Tags: .net-core

I want to build a base controller that I can put some reusable methods so I do not have to put a bunch of repeat code in all my controllers. So I built a BaseController.cs

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

    public BaseController(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }
}
```

Then in one of my contollers I do `public class TokenController : BaseController`. But then it wants me to add the following but then it gives me errors

```
public TokenController(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
{
    // I guess something goes here
}
```

But then VS Code tells me

```
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'clientFactory' of 'BaseController.BaseController(IHttpClientFactory)' (CS7036)
```

What am I missing here? I been in JS world to long :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inheriting classes without default constructors you have to pass parameters to them using the following syntax:

```
public TokenController(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory) : base (clientFactory)
{
  /* other initializations */
}
```

So add the following expression: **: base (clientFactory)**

See more information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors